# Cannot start Universal Windows Platform app (nothing happens)

Tags: c#, uwp, visual-studio-2019

hope my question will find you safe and healthy!

Quick question, I've created a UWP project (blank app) in Visual Studio 2019. When I try to start debugging the application, the app is built without error but nothing starts. Same thing if I try to start the application using the exe file in the output folder.

- The checkbox "Do not start, but debug my code when it starts" is unchecked in project properties
- Target & min versions are Windows 10, version 1809 (which is the W10 version installed on the computer).
- No error in event viewer (verified in all aplication logs)
- The app is new and is not already installed

Do you know how I can start the app and show the default main window?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: When you run the app from visual studio, you said that nothing starts. Is the visual studio still in debug mode at that time? In other words, did the debug button- the green arrow change to a red block button?  Or the visual studio just builds the app and the debug button change to the green arrow again? And after that, is the app installed in your device?  If it is installed, could you launch from the start menu because UWP apps could not be launched via a .exe file?

Comment: It went to red then back to green almost immediately. It finally worked after setting to x86 as active solution platform in the configuration manager.

Comment: Glad to hear that. You could mark your own reply so that this might help others

Answer (score 1):

Worked after setting the active solution platform to x86 for the whole project.